# reordering facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I've been through the examples for changing facet orders on the site but can't seem to get anything to work for my specific case.  Any ideas of how to do this with my data setup would be much appreciated. I'm somewhat new to ggplot2 and am supremely stumped.  I would like my models to be ordered M1, M2, M3 with M1 on the top of each facet. Thanks!

```
Outcome<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
OR<-c(1.97,2.47,3.56,1.73,2.25,4.09,1.21,1.48,2.25)
min<-c(1.37,1.74,2.55,1.13,1.52,2.84,0.74,0.95,1.49)
max<-c(2.83,3.49,4.98,2.66,3.35,5.9,1.97,2.33,3.41)
Aces<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
ace<-data.frame(cbind(Outcome,OR,min,max,Aces))

ace_labels <- list('1'="1 ACE",'2'="2 ACEs",'3'="3 ACEs")

ace_labeller <- function(variable,value){return(ace_labels[value])}

ace$Outcome = factor(ace$Outcome, levels=c("1","2","3"), 
                 labels=c("M1: Depression","M2: MH Barrier to Work",
                          "M3: MH Barrier to Work"))            

ggplot(data=ace,aes(x=OR,y=Outcome,label=OR))+
geom_point(aes(size=8))+
geom_text(size=5,vjust=1.8)+
geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=min,xmax=max),height=.1)+
geom_vline(xintercept=1,linetype="dashed")+
scale_x_log10(breaks=seq(1,6,1),name="Figure 1: Odds Ratios (OR) and 95% Confidence Intervals for Models 1, 2 and 3 (N=1073)
            \nEach OR is compared to 0 ACEs")+
labs(y="")+
facet_grid(Aces~., labeller=ace_labeller)+
guides(size=FALSE)+
theme_bw()+
theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=12))+
theme(strip.text.y=element_text(size = 12))+
theme(axis.title.x=element_text(face="italic", size = 12,hjust=.5))
```

[image]

Comment: If you want help you should supply some useful data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reverse your labels you set up for `ace$Outcome` you can get it to plot M1 on top, M2, and M3 on the bottom in each facet.

Just change:

```
ace$Outcome = factor(ace$Outcome, levels=c("3","2","1"), 
             labels=c("M3: MH Barrier to Work",
                      "M2: MH Barrier to Work",
                      "M1: Depression"))
```

Using your same sample data and plot code it produces:

[image]

Your code (with only the noted above changed):

```
Outcome<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
OR<-c(1.97,2.47,3.56,1.73,2.25,4.09,1.21,1.48,2.25)
min<-c(1.37,1.74,2.55,1.13,1.52,2.84,0.74,0.95,1.49)
max<-c(2.83,3.49,4.98,2.66,3.35,5.9,1.97,2.33,3.41)
Aces<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
ace<-data.frame(cbind(Outcome,OR,min,max,Aces))

ace_labels <- list('1'="1 ACE",'2'="2 ACEs",'3'="3 ACEs")

ace_labeller <- function(variable,value){return(ace_labels[value])}

ace$Outcome = factor(ace$Outcome, levels=c("3","2","1"), 
                 labels=c("M3: MH Barrier to Work",
                          "M2: MH Barrier to Work",
                          "M1: Depression"))            

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=ace,aes(x=OR,y=Outcome,label=OR))+
geom_point(aes(size=8))+
geom_text(size=5,vjust=1.8)+
geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=min,xmax=max),height=.1)+
geom_vline(xintercept=1,linetype="dashed")+
scale_x_log10(breaks=seq(1,6,1),name="Figure 1: Odds Ratios (OR) and 95% Confidence Intervals for Models 1, 2 and 3 (N=1073)
            \nEach OR is compared to 0 ACEs")+
labs(y="")+
facet_grid(Aces~., labeller=ace_labeller)+
guides(size=FALSE)+
theme_bw()+
theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=12))+
theme(strip.text.y=element_text(size = 12))+
theme(axis.title.x=element_text(face="italic", size = 12,hjust=.5))
```